# Samsung Galaxy M11 and Samsung Galaxy M01s not able to install 64bit apps from google play store even while having 64bit chipsets

Tags: applications, samsung, rom-flashing

Samsung Galaxy M11 has a Qualcomm SDM450 Snapdragon 450 chipset while the Samsung Galaxy M01s has a Mediatek MT6762 Helio P22 chipset. Going to their websites, on Qualcomm and Mediatek respectively, shows that they both support 64bit. However as mentioned in the title, the two phones are unable to install 64bit apps from the Google Play Store. I am suspecting that the reason for this is because their OSs might be 32bit. (I can't check personally because someone else has the phones and I am trying to solve a problem for them.) If that is the case, is it wise to flash a 64bit OS to the phones to be able to run 64bit apps?
Below are the links to the chipset specs on their respective websites:

https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-450-mobile-platform

https://www.mediatek.com/products/smartphones/mediatek-helio-p22

Comment: Are you sure the installation fails because of the device not supporting 64bit apps? There are other reasons why an installation may fail. Please tell us what apps you have tried to install (best with link to PlayStore), how you tried to install them and what error you got.